# What are the mandarin words for these Chinese altars?

Tags: vocabulary, culture

I saw some various types of Chinese altars in some chinese countries:

1. Altar that hanging on wall (I suppose this is altar for sky god): https://www.flickr.com/photos/ripi/3969597088/in/set-72157622488573560
2. Earth deity altar (usually put on ground level): http://thaiworldview.com/hongkong/newterritories/jpg/img733.jpg
3. Table altar: http://lh4.ggpht.com/-Okyt6PnpVYg/UTNTRH3kmBI/AAAAAAAAFbc/9bg9ZsX4CrE/IMG_1667_thumb%25255B2%25255D.jpg?imgmax=800

I would like to know the mandarin words for those kind of altars if they are any.

Comment: 龛(儿) kān or kār, would be a pretty good bet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you can call all of them as 神位 which means place of god.

If you are referring to the facilities offering the places,

> 1. Altar that hanging on wall (I suppose this is altar for sky god):

龛 as @user3306356 mentioned, means small box used as altar. you describe them as  神龛，佛龛 ..

> 2.Earth deity altar (usually put on ground level):

personally , 龛 is also suitable for this , thought they are of different size.

> 3.Table altar:

供桌 a table for offering sacrifices.

Comment: So there is no specialized term for each type of altar, maybe like 土地公龕 or 土地公神位? Also I heard someone use term 神主 for the altar? Is it correct too?

Comment: god name(土地公) and 龕/神位 can be combined to specify a certain altar. 土地公神位 equals to 土地公的神位， where ‘的’ can be omitted, just like 我的家 and 我家。


I don't know much about '神主',